# Get Recent App Button Clicked in Launcher App

Tags: java, android, kiosk-mode

I am writing a launcher application which will launch other apps on its `OnCreate` method. Following is the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ......

     Intent i = PckManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.app.myApp");
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    LaunchMe.this.startActivity(i);
```

Now on `OnResume` of `LauncherApp`, I am restarting my desired app to be remain at top using following code:

```
 protected void onResume() {
    Intent i = PckManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.yego.motodriver");
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    LaunchMe.this.startActivity(i);
    super.onResume();
}
```

This ensures that MyApp will always remain on top of the activities when user clicked Home or Back button of device.

But when user clicks `RecentApp` button of device, I could not get any event fire in `LauncherApp` Neither `OnResume` nor `OnPause` or `OnWindowFocusedChanged`.

I need to stop the user to get into the Recent Acitivities tab and want MyApp to always remain on the top of the activities.

I have Checked some apps like SureLock and GoKiosk able to prevent the user from going into Recent App tab. How do they manage this?